# Handling null decimal values in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, sql-server-2019, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a model in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC data context that accepts a certain decimal value, `myNullableDecimal`. This value needs to be nullable, since "0.00" would be interpreted downstream as a valid, or non-null, response. So, I set the corresponding column in my SQL Server 2019 database table, to which the context will connect, to accept null values in the table designer. In my model, I declare the field like this:

```
public decimal? myNullableDecimal { get; set; }
```

This way, if the user chooses to provide a value, it gets stored, and if not, the db takes the null. When I submit new data, the validation goes through with no problem, and input is saved in the database. However, when I run a `.ToList()` linq query on the table that contains my nullable decimal column:

```
List<myTableModel> myData = (from t in _context.myTable
                             select t).ToList();
```

I get an error

> This method or property cannot be called on null value.

The error is thrown from `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal()`. If I update my column to contain a non-null value, the query works, but like I said, any non-null value in this column must be interpreted as valid, so defaulting this column to zero won't work.

I don't want to set the column as a string, since that would require me to convert my value to a decimal later on. I've tried setting a default value for my column in my model,

```
public decimal? myNullableDecimal { get; set; } = 0
```

but I still get the error. I understand from [this ancient article](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) that a custom model binder might hold the solution, but that same article warns against using them. What else can I do get around this error?

EDIT: The problem seems to lie in the fact that I have the MVC field for myNullableDecimal marked as [Required]. If I take away the requirement, a null value is no problem. But, once again, I can't do that because when the myNullableDecimal input field is presented to the user, the user is expected to enter a value here (it's hidden by default.) So, the full field declaration for myNullableDecimal in my model is:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a value")]
public decimal? myNullableDecimal {get; set;} = 0
```

Apologies for not mentioning this sooner; I didn't realize the requirement mark made a difference in this case.

Comment: Tricky one this is.. Can you just exclude the null ones alltogether? `var myDataNotNull = _context.myTable.Where(d => d.myNullableDecimal != null).select(d => d.t).ToList();`

Comment: @flashsplat unfortunately, no, because the column itself is optional; a non-null value only needs to go there under certain conditions. It's possible that I'll need to pull lists where myNullableDecimal is null in some rows and not null in others.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as you mentioned,At first,I did not set the [Required]Attribute on

```
decimal? myNullableDecimal { get; set; }
```

The column could be null:

[image]

Then I set the [Required]Attribute on the property,The column became not null after you add migration and update database:

[image]

I checked the document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties

Although I don't kown the details of your database ,but if you want to validate the property with [required ] Attribute and keep the myNullableDecimal could be null in your database, you could try to create a ViewModel and map it to Entity， add the [Required]attribute on the property of ViewModel,remove it in your Entity